# Can you attach external worker nodes to Managed Kubernetes Control Plane? If yes, how to attach them?

Tags: kubernetes

I know many services provided a managed control plane. GKE, Digital Ocean.  I want a Kubernetes cluster using those service as they provide reliablity. But I want to expand my kubernetes cluster using a number of physical machines, old machines, raspberry pis etc that I have in my local office.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do that?

I found two questions in stackoverflow related to this, but both go with unsatisfactory answers

- [Add external node to GCP Kubernetes Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270198/add-external-node-to-gcp-kubernetes-cluster)

Here the answer seems to be using `kubeadm init` - which really is not about adding a worker node, but doing making the control plane HA.

- [GKE with Aws worker nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854968/gke-with-aws-worker-nodes)

Says it is possible, but does not mention how to add external worker nodes.

Comment: Do you have admin access (a kubeconfig with admin account) to the kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: Yes, this kubernetes control plane cluster was created by me.

Comment: Ado you have permission to ssh into the master nodes ?can you post the output of kubectl get cm -n kube-system and kubectl get secrets -n kube-system

Comment: Which of the cloud providers do you intend to use for this theoretical implementation?

Comment: The architecture that you are trying to achieve by merging cloud managed cluster with self provisioned nodes could lead to reliability issues. Besides that there will be network related problems and all changes should be done with direct insertion to `etcd`.  And it's really dependent on the cloud provider with related security policies.

Comment: @DawidKruk - Acknowledge. In my research, Google Anthos seems to be only project with support for just on-prem VMware nodes as the available ones. I was trying "know the details" for any cloud provider, for instance, Digital Ocean. If was not possible, figure out "why".